In each column of a data frame , how to find out the duration for which each unique value in a column existed?
Example , consider the
df:
   Time     colA    colB
0     1.1      2     2
1     2.2      2     2
2     3.4      3     5
3     4.5      3     5
4     5.6      4     5
5     6.2      4     6
6     7.4      4     6
7     8.5      2     6
8     9.8      2     5 
9     10.1     2     5
10    11.2     2     5

The ouptut I am expecting is a report CSV file with the columns as follows :
Col_name    unique_value   Duration

colA             2             3.8s 
colA             3             1.1s
colA             4             1.8s
colB             2             1.1s
colB             5             3.6s
colB             6             2.3s

(eg): To calculate colA :
unique value = 2
Duration = [1st consecutive appearance of 2 time difference (2.2-1.1)] + [2nd consecutive appearance time difference (11.2-8.5)] = 1.1 + 2.7 = 3.8s 

One of the logics I tried is :

Create a new column that will calculate the difference of consecutive values in a column and give the output True - if there is consecutive values & False - if there are diff values one after other.

df["answer"] = df['colA'].diff().eq(0)

As next step, I was planning to get all the False in one list and True in one list and get the difference of the list .

How to link these with unique values, is what I am confused of.


Do help me figure out if the existing logic works or if should change the logic

*To create a new column indicating consecutive values with True and False is a good start. However, to calculate the duration for each unique value in each column, you can use the following steps:
Iterate over each unique value in each column.
For each unique value, find the consecutive occurrences and calculate the duration.
Store the results in a new Data Frame.
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'Time': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'colA': [1.1, 2.2, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6, 6.2, 7.4, 8.5, 9.8, 10.1, 11.2],
    'colB': [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to calculate duration for each unique value in a column
def calculate_duration(column_name):
    durations = []
    unique_values = df[column_name].unique()
    for value in unique_values:
        # Find consecutive occurrences of the value
        consecutive_indices = df[df[column_name] == value].index.to_list()
        consecutive_occurrences = []
        current_occurrence = [consecutive_indices[0]]
        for i in range(1, len(consecutive_indices)):
            if consecutive_indices[i] - consecutive_indices[i-1] == 1:
                current_occurrence.append(consecutive_indices[i])
            else:
                consecutive_occurrences.append(current_occurrence)
                current_occurrence = [consecutive_indices[i]]
        consecutive_occurrences.append(current_occurrence)
        
        # Calculate duration for each consecutive occurrence
        for occurrence in consecutive_occurrences:
            start_time = df.iloc[occurrence[0]]['Time']
            end_time = df.iloc[occurrence[-1]]['Time']
            duration = end_time - start_time
            durations.append((value, duration))
    return durations

# Create a DataFrame to store results
report_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col_name', 'unique_value', 'Duration'])

# Calculate durations for each column
for column in df.columns[1:]:
    durations = calculate_duration(column)
    for value, duration in durations:
        report_df = report_df.append({'Col_name': column, 'unique_value': value, 'Duration': duration}, ignore_index=True)

# Export to CSV
report_df.to_csv('report.csv', index=False)

Export the Data Frame to a CSV file.*

This is amazing ! Thank you so much for the lightening fast response. I do have one query though . The way I typed the columns and the way it appeared has actually confused the column inputs I guess. I interchanged and did run your code to which my output is : unique values for the column colA is :  [2 5 6]
output durations for this column :  [(2, 2.3), (5, 1.7000000000000002), (5, 1.3999999999999986), (6, 1.0999999999999996)]. Here If you can see I intentionally repeated value 5 with another number in between . Where would I modify for the code to consider these 5's together ?

For your reference this is the df I used :     # Sample DataFrame
data = {
'Time': [1.1, 2.2, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6, 6.2, 7.4, 8.5, 9.8, 10.1, 11.2],
'colA': [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5],
'colB': [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2]
}

I think loop here is not necessary, use pandas methods:
df1 = df.melt('Time')
s = df1['value'].ne(df1['value'].shift()).cumsum().rename('g')
out = (df1.groupby(['variable', 'value', s])['Time']
          .agg(['first','last'])
          .assign(dif=lambda x: x['last'].sub(x['first']))
          .groupby(['variable', 'value'])['dif'].sum()
          .rename_axis(['Col_name','unique_value'])
          .reset_index(name='Duration')
          )
print (out)
  Col_name  unique_value  Duration
0     colA             2       3.8
1     colA             3       1.1
2     colA             4       1.8
3     colB             2       1.1
4     colB             5       3.6
5     colB             6       2.3

Output with new data from comment:
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Time': [1.1, 2.2, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6, 6.2, 7.4, 8.5, 9.8, 10.1, 11.2], 
                   'colA': [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5],
                   'colB': [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2] })

df1 = df.melt('Time')
s = df1['value'].ne(df1['value'].shift()).cumsum().rename('g')
out = (df1.groupby(['variable', 'value', s])['Time']
          .agg(['first','last'])
          .assign(dif=lambda x: x['last'].sub(x['first']))
          .groupby(['variable', 'value'])['dif'].sum()
          .rename_axis(['Col_name','unique_value'])
          .reset_index(name='Duration')
          )
print (out)
  Col_name  unique_value  Duration
0     colA             2       2.3
1     colA             5       3.1
2     colA             6       1.1
3     colB             2       3.8
4     colB             3       1.1
5     colB             4       1.8

How it working:
First unpivot values by DataFrame.melt:
df1 = df.melt('Time')
print (df1)
    Time variable  value
0    1.1     colA      2
1    2.2     colA      2
2    3.4     colA      2
3    4.5     colA      5
4    5.6     colA      5
5    6.2     colA      5
6    7.4     colA      6
7    8.5     colA      6
8    9.8     colA      5
9   10.1     colA      5
10  11.2     colA      5
11   1.1     colB      2
12   2.2     colB      2
13   3.4     colB      3
14   4.5     colB      3
15   5.6     colB      4
16   6.2     colB      4
17   7.4     colB      4
18   8.5     colB      2
19   9.8     colB      2
20  10.1     colB      2
21  11.2     colB      2

Create Series of sonsecutive values:
print (df1.assign(g=s))
    Time variable  value  g
0    1.1     colA      2  1
1    2.2     colA      2  1
2    3.4     colA      2  1
3    4.5     colA      5  2
4    5.6     colA      5  2
5    6.2     colA      5  2
6    7.4     colA      6  3
7    8.5     colA      6  3
8    9.8     colA      5  4
9   10.1     colA      5  4
10  11.2     colA      5  4
11   1.1     colB      2  5
12   2.2     colB      2  5
13   3.4     colB      3  6
14   4.5     colB      3  6
15   5.6     colB      4  7
16   6.2     colB      4  7
17   7.4     colB      4  7
18   8.5     colB      2  8
19   9.8     colB      2  8
20  10.1     colB      2  8
21  11.2     colB      2  8

Aggregate by consecutive unique_value by helper s Series with GroupBy.first and
GroupBy.last values per groups:
print (df1.groupby(['variable', 'value', s])['Time']
          .agg(['first','last']))

                  first  last
variable value g             
colA     2     1    1.1   3.4
         5     2    4.5   6.2
               4    9.8  11.2
         6     3    7.4   8.5
colB     2     5    1.1   2.2
               8    8.5  11.2
         3     6    3.4   4.5
         4     7    5.6   7.4

Subtract columns for difference:
print (df1.groupby(['variable', 'value', s])['Time']
          .agg(['first','last'])
          .assign(dif=lambda x: x['last'].sub(x['first'])))
                  first  last  dif
variable value g                  
colA     2     1    1.1   3.4  2.3
         5     2    4.5   6.2  1.7
               4    9.8  11.2  1.4
         6     3    7.4   8.5  1.1
colB     2     5    1.1   2.2  1.1
               8    8.5  11.2  2.7
         3     6    3.4   4.5  1.1
         4     7    5.6   7.4  1.8

And sum per groups for final time:
print (df1.groupby(['variable', 'value', s])['Time']
          .agg(['first','last'])
          .assign(dif=lambda x: x['last'].sub(x['first']))
          .groupby(['variable', 'value'])['dif'].sum())

variable  value
colA      2        2.3
          5        3.1
          6        1.1
colB      2        3.8
          3        1.1
          4        1.8
Name: dif, dtype: float64

Last rename index names and convert to DataFrame:
s = df1['value'].ne(df1['value'].shift()).cumsum().rename('g')
out = (df1.groupby(['variable', 'value', s])['Time']
          .agg(['first','last'])
          .assign(dif=lambda x: x['last'].sub(x['first']))
          .groupby(['variable', 'value'])['dif'].sum()
          .rename_axis(['Col_name','unique_value'])
          .reset_index(name='Duration')
          )

print (out)
  Col_name  unique_value  Duration
0     colA             2       2.3
1     colA             5       3.1
2     colA             6       1.1
3     colB             2       3.8
4     colB             3       1.1
5     colB             4       1.8


That's an amazing use of pandas. Thank you for your answer
